# Is it possible to export the width and height of a string to an external program writing native Postscript

Tags: postscript

I have a program that writes Postscript code to draw various diagrams using a Postscript graphics library. I would like to know in the main program what the actual size (height and length) of the text strings will be so that I can calculate overlaps and attempt to do something about them. I use Ghostscript to view the files and to convert them to other formats so in principle could execute that as a system command but I'm not sure if this would help. I am only a novice Postscript user.

I have looked at stringwidth but haven't worked out how to use it to get the data back to the main program.

Comment: The only way to return information from a **separate** process (ie using Ghostscript) would be to write the information to a 'file'. You can use stdout or stderr directly or you can use the PostScript file operators to open a file on disk and write the information to it. If you use a file you will need to expressly permit Ghostscript to write to it with --permit-file-write=.... Other than that your PostScript graphics library may have some means of communicating with the main process, but that would be specific to your library, so can't help with that.

Comment: Thanks very much - that is what I was hoping for - write a Postscript file containing the string (s) to a temporary file, execute this with Ghostscript which will write the output parameters to another disk file and then read in this. That is the strategy. I will now have to put some time aside to learn enough Postscript to do it. The library does not deal with external files other than the one it is writing the main Postscript code to.

Comment: You could calculate the overlap in postscript itself using the `charpath` and `pathbbox` operators but probably will need to transform them to a common corrdinate system and maybe even harder to re-position them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. In the end, I have saved the critical font metrics (especially the character widths) from the relevant afm files and then used these to calculate the string width within my program. This avoids inter-process communication. I found the afm files in my Python/matplotlib installation. This seems to work well and I have even learned a bit more about Postscript fonts! I now know precisely where text will be printed in both my plotting coordinates and in inches.  I should have done this a long time ago.